# Centert align vertically element when container height is unknown

Tags: css

I have a row of two columns, one column contains an image and the other column some text. Is there a way I can always vertically align the text within the column so that it is always centered vertically? You can see an example here on the fourth and fifth row of what I'm trying to do:

http://machinas.com/wip/hugoboss/responsive-img/

The height depends on the size of the image really so I can't really set a height of the column.

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-6 column">
        <div class="txt-block">
            <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor</h3>         
            <p>Vivamus eget tempus magna. Proin dignissim, est ac mollis viverra, ligula leo fringilla dolor, in porttitor quam lectus eget augue. Etiam vel felis at mauris pellentesque cursus dignissim in nunc.</p>    
            <div class="center-wrap">
                <div class="center">
                    <a href="link" class="jetzt-entdeck">Jetzt entdecken</a>
                </div>
            </div>   
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="large-6 column">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/470x400" alt="">
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.column {
    display: table;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    padding-left: 0.5rem;
    padding-right: 0.5rem;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Please post your code within the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove floats on the large-6 column div and add vertical align middle, also you should be displaying those as table-cells not tables. The row is acting as a table. See css below;

```
.large-6.column {
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: but if I put float:none then it will not display in columns :S

Comment: large-6 is a column, you have even named it column... You are creating a table with divs, row is surrounding the 2 divs, i have done this fix in firebug and it all works fine, what problem are you getting exactly?

Comment: If you are reffering to the 5th row, you need to remove the right class of this, and swap around the large-6 column div so that the image col is first then the text col. basically swapping them round from the 4th row. Do this and add my css it will work :)

Comment: Hi, yes you're right it works thanks, but on that fifth row, I really need the float right to make the image appear first and the on mobile the text appears first.

Comment: You can play around with `direction: rtl;` and `direction: ltr;` that will switch order of displaying your cells.

Comment: those don't do anything :(

Comment: directotion: rtl; does not work in this instance @norin89. Unfortunateley if you need this to be displayed right then html needs to be structured so that the image is first then the text. using php you should be able to make this do that every 2nd row

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need IE8 support then you can use CSS3 `transform`. In your case set `top: 50%` to your `.txt-block` and add `transform: translateY(-50%);` what will move the element 50% of it's height to the top.

[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/norin89/59ukdr1y/)

**UPDATE**
Other good solution is to style your `div`s a table instead of `float`ing and use `vertical-align: middle;` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25380378/3589528) by @Jay.